# General Topology - First and Second Countable

Tags: general-topology

Consider the topology $\tau(\mathcal{E})$ on $\mathbb{R}$ generated by $\mathcal{E} = \{N(x,\epsilon) : x \in \mathbb{R}, \epsilon > 0\}$ and

$
N(x;\epsilon) = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      \mathbb{Q} \cap (x - \epsilon, x + \epsilon) & \text{ if } x \in \mathbb{Q} \\
      (x - \epsilon, x + \epsilon) \setminus \mathbb{Q} & \text{ if } x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q} \\
\end{array} 
\right.$

Is this space first and second countable?

Here are my ideas:

I think it is not first countable because for all $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $x \in \mathbb{P}$, $N(x,\epsilon)$ can act as a nbd base at $x$. However, $\forall x \in \mathbb{P}$, the nbd base $N(x,\epsilon)$ is uncountable.

Then if the space is not first countable then it is not second countable.

Comment: What is $\mathbb P$?

Comment: $ N(x,\epsilon)$ is just one set, so it's (probably) not a neighborhood base. To get a neighborhood base at $x$ you need to use a whole bunch of different $\epsilon$'s. For example, I think $\{N(x,1),N(x,\frac12), N(x,\frac13),\dots,N(x,\frac1n),\dots\}$ might be a neighborhood base at $x$.

Comment: @bof $\Bbb P$ is the set of irrational numbers in $\Bbb R$. So we have $\Bbb P \cup \Bbb Q=\Bbb R$.

Comment: Each or $\Bbb Q$ and $\Bbb P=\Bbb R\setminus \Bbb Q$ is both open and closed in this topology, and has the topology induced by the real line. So each is second countable, and their disjoint union is second countable too. There may be one base that is uncountable, and another base that is countable. I believe you are overlooking the second possibility. A space is second countable if there is at least one base that is countable. It is not necessary that every base (in particular one used to define the topology) is countable.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I could have guesses that $\mathbb Q$ is the set of irrationals. But I had to ask to be sure, because (unlike $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb Q$) it's not a standard notation. Or so I thought. From your comment I gather that $\mathbb Q$ *is* a standard notation and my ignorance is showing again.

Comment: @bof it is not “standard” really, but common enough to denote the irrationals by $\Bbb P$, especially among topologists. Also $\Bbb S$ is sometimes used for the Sorgenfrey line (the reals in the lower limit topology).

Answer (score 1):

It's second countable. Let $x_n$ be an injective sequence that ranges over $\Bbb{Q}$, and $y_n$ be an injective sequence that is dense in $\Bbb{R} \setminus \Bbb{Q}$. Form a basis for the topology like so:
$$B = \left\{\Bbb{Q} \cap \left(x_n - \frac{1}{m}, x_n + \frac{1}{m}\right) : n, m \in \Bbb{N}\right\} \cup \left\{\left(y_n - \frac{1}{m}, y_n + \frac{1}{m}\right) \setminus \Bbb{Q} : n, m \in \Bbb{N}\right\}.$$
Note that $B$ is countable. It's clear that every neighbourhood $\Bbb{Q} \cap \left(x - \varepsilon, x + \varepsilon\right)$, where $x \in \Bbb{Q}$, contains a set in $B$, as $x = x_n$ for some $n$.

On the other hand, consider some $y \in \Bbb{R} \setminus \Bbb{Q}$, and $\varepsilon > 0$. Since $y_n$ is dense in $\Bbb{R} \setminus \Bbb{Q}$, there must be some $n$ such that $|y - y_n| < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$. Choose $m$ such that $\frac{1}{m} < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ Then,
$$\left(y_n - \frac{1}{m}, y_n + \frac{1}{m}\right) \setminus \Bbb{Q} \subseteq \left(y_n - \frac{\varepsilon}{2}, y_n + \frac{\varepsilon}{2}\right) \setminus \Bbb{Q} \subseteq \left(y - \varepsilon, y + \varepsilon\right) \setminus \Bbb{Q}.$$
Thus, every neighbourhood in the original basis is contains a set from $B$, thus $B$ is also a basis, and countable to boot.

Comment: wouldn't $(p,q)\cap\Bbb Q$, and $(p,q)\setminus\Bbb Q$, when $p,q$ range over $\Bbb Q$, form a countable basis?